# How do I remove gaps between two wavefront OBJ layers?

Tags: rendering, mesh, objects

I have generated two wavefront OBJ layers - a terrain surface from GeoTIFF to TIN to OBJ and some buildings from shapefile to extruded shape to OBJ - using Safe Software's FME.  In the FME previewer the two layers sit flush but when I import to Blender (2.78a on Windows 7 64bit) and render a scene the buildings are floating above the surface.

In the image below you can see the odd white line above the black hole of the building footprint.  I also created a single OBJ file by combining the surface and the buildings and embedded the buildings into the surface by offsetting in the Z axis by -1m. The problem persists in Blender.

Is there anything I can do within Blender to move the buildings into position?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use [this](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) to upload blend files.

Comment: Making normals consistent did not make any noticeable difference. The terrain is made from a 10m DTM and the buildings are Ordnance Survey buildings.

Comment: The building mesh and face normals appear to be all-over the place. Selecting all in edit mode and making normals consistent Ctrl-N does help somewhat? Are they OSM buildings?  Also your locations are ridiculous (world coordinates?)  Here I've transformed the origin to geometry of mesh and moved the mesh to (0,0,0) , scaled a bit and moved the cam/ lamp.  http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=108851

Comment: Ah, the OBJ files were created with British National Grid projection hence the coordinates being such big numbers.  Setting Origin to Geometry and Location to 0,0,0 did the trick. Thank you! [I was too quick off the mark with the last comment.]

Comment: np, have you tried the blenderGIS addon?  https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS it's very good.  Been playing around with an OSM importer that uses pyosmium, ... roofs are doing my head in.  Please feel free to write up your own answer I'm going to hit the hay.

Comment: Yes, I've been using BlenderGIS for creating hill shaded relief maps. Lovely effects.

Answer (score 1):

The imported OBJ files were projected to the British National Grid (EPSG:27700) and as a result they were located very far from the origin. So, selecting the layer and setting `Origin to Geometry` and then updating the Location to `(0,0,0)` results in the buildings sitting flush on the surface.

[image]

Thanks to suggestions from [batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger)